# Is there a way to make the legend in matplotlib fit better within the plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to plot a line plot with multiple lines.

Due to a large number of lines, the legend gets so large that it hides some of the lines, is there a way to automatically set the y ticks so that there will be enough room in the plot for the legend to fit properly?

Example plot:

[image: Example plot]

Thank you.

Comment: I would just plot the legend outside the plot area, something like `ax.legend(loc=[1,0.5])`

Comment: you could also add another, smaller, axes object using gridspec to give you more space to add the legend

Comment: You could also try `ax.set_ylim(0, 4.5)`

Comment: Just place the legend outside. See [How to put the legend out of the plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700614/how-to-put-the-legend-out-of-the-plot/43439132#43439132).

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust the `xlim` and the dict `prop`, for example

```
x = np.linspace(1,10,10)
y = x + np.random.rand(10,10)
labels = list('abcdefghij')

fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,6))
ax.plot(x,y,'-o')

ax.set_xlim(1,11)
ax.legend(labels,loc='upper right', prop={'size': 10})
```

[image: plot]

Tuning `ax.set_xlim` to leave enough space for the legend, and the size of the legend is controlled by `prop={'size':10}`